# Measuring current with a multimeter around a closed circuit

Tags: current, multimeter, physics

A question from physics lab:

> Referring to the circuit you built to measure currents, what would happen if we completed our circuit with a wire and measured the current with the multimeter at the same two points? 
> Think of Kirchhoff’s laws.
>
> [image: Circuit for measuring current]

I understand that the multimeter will give a reading of zero but I do not understand how to explain it using Kirchoff's Laws. Would it be the net voltage loop rule? Would it be the junction rule? Or does it have something to do with the path of least resistance?

Comment: Sounds like it means to connect the ammeter in parallel to a short (wire). It might read some non-zero value depending on the ratio between the wire resistance and the ammeter itself. In terms of KCL the current measured + the current in the wire will be the current in the circuit. Hard to tell more without the circuit details.

Comment: I think the instructions mean to complete the circuit by attaching the other side of the resistor to the negative terminal, and then measure the current between the points you're measuring at above.

Comment: I guess the "at the same two points" should be clarified. Which points?

Answer (score 1):

If you complete the circuit with a wire at the same two points as the multimeter probes, you short out the meter - the meter will not register any current (or a negligible amount of current depending on meter sensitivity/range and wire resistance). This is because (presumably) the wire has an ultra low impedance and the internals of the ammeter have a high impedance (relative to a short piece of wire).

From the standpoint of (*academic) Kirchhoff, this new node created from the wire is at the same potential at both DMM leads across the wire - the wire has no resistance in this framework - which means there is no voltage drop across the wire. The loop is not broken, rather, it is augmented with a short, therefore, the circuit behavior and also the current prior to the short, does not change and the circuit works exactly as it did prior to shorting out the meter.